# Add swagger group in Jhipster

Tags: swagger, jhipster

In Jhipster default there are two groups on the Swagger page. The default group and a managment group. I would like to add a third group, lets say api2.

Here is the selection box for default:
[image]

And here for managment:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just got a pointer elsewhere. Here is the solution. Add a this class to your config:

```
package nl.tibi.config;

import static io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnWebApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import io.github.jhipster.config.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration;
import springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

/**
 * An extension of the default Jhipster {@link SwaggerAutoConfiguration} adding
 * the pluginV1 group
 */
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnClass({
        ApiInfo.class,
        BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class,
        Servlet.class,
        DispatcherServlet.class,
        Docket.class
})
@Profile(SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER)
@AutoConfigureAfter(JHipsterProperties.class)
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerExtension {

    static final String STARTING_MESSAGE = "Starting Swagger";
    static final String STARTED_MESSAGE = "Started Swagger in {} ms";
    static final String PLUGIN_V1_TITLE_SUFFIX = "Plugin V1 API";
    static final String PLUGIN_V1_GROUP_NAME = "pluginV1";
    static final String PLUGIN_V1_DESCRIPTION = "Plugin V1 endpoints documentation";

    private final JHipsterProperties.Swagger properties;

    /**
     * <p>
     * Constructor for SwaggerAutoConfiguration.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param jHipsterProperties a
     *                           {@link io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties}
     *                           object.
     */
    public SwaggerExtension(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.properties = jHipsterProperties.getSwagger();
    }

    /**
     * Springfox configuration for the plugin v1 endpoints (actuator) Swagger docs.
     *
     * @param appName               the application name
     * @return the Swagger Springfox configuration
     */
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringfoxPluginV1Docket(@Value("${spring.application.name:application}") String appName) {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                StringUtils.capitalize(appName) + " " + PLUGIN_V1_TITLE_SUFFIX,
                PLUGIN_V1_DESCRIPTION,
                properties.getVersion(),
                "",
                ApiInfo.DEFAULT_CONTACT,
                "",
                "",
                new ArrayList<>());

        return createDocket()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(properties.isUseDefaultResponseMessages())
                .groupName("pluginV1")
                .host(properties.getHost())
                .protocols(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(properties.getProtocols())))
                .forCodeGeneration(true)
                .directModelSubstitute(ByteBuffer.class, String.class)
                .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .ignoredParameterTypes(Pageable.class)
                .select()
                .paths(regex("/api/plugin/v1.*"))
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * createDocket.
     * </p>
     *
     * @return a {@link springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket} object.
     */
    protected Docket createDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
    }
}
```